# Post Increment operator on operands

Tags: java, c#

```
public static void main(String []args)
{    
     char x = 'A';    
     System.out.println(x++ + ++x);         //In Java
     Console.WriteLine(x++ + ++x);          // In C#
}
```

In the sample program above I was expecting the output to be 133 .Here is how I evaluated .
Since both post and pre increments take precedence over '+' ,it will get evaluated first

Step 1: System.out.println(66 + 67)

Step 2: System.out.println(133)

When will the x become 66 in the post increment operation . Is it in the next line that the value becomes 66 , I am a bit confused in this regard .

Comment: And the C# link is.....?

Comment: The answer would be 65+67=132

Answer (score 0):

65 + 67 because x++ will perform after the line has finished executing and ++x will perform during execution.

Comment: `x++` increments the value by 1 not "after the line", but after expression `x++` returned the value. And expression `++x` increments the value by 1 before it returns the value.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak To be very pedantic,  the postfix operator will temporarily save the contents of `x`, then increment the variable `x` and then return the saved contents. An operator is very similiar to a function and a function cannot *do* something after it has returned.

Answer (score 0):

The `x` becomes `66` soon, after the + operator. After that operator, the `x` is again incremented so it becomes `66+1`. Therefore, it looks like this: `65+67` which is `132`.

When considering what the computer actually does...
 
   x++: load x from memory, use, increment, store back to memory.
 
 
    ++x: load x from memory, increment, use, store back to memory.